# ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova prepare (exit code 1):

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, node-modules, ionic-native

> [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova prepare (exit code 1):

```
    Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-camera" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
    Installing "cordova-plugin-camera" for android
    Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-camera': CordovaError: Version of installed plugin:
    "cordova-plugin-compat@1.0.0" does not satisfy dependency plugin requirement "cordova-plugin-compat@^1.1.0". Try
    --force to use installed plugin as dependency.
    at C:\Users\******\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\install.js:581:33
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\******\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\******\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch
    (C:\Users\******\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
    at C:\Users\******\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:509:49
    at flush (C:\Users\******\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    Failed to restore plugin "cordova-plugin-camera" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error:
    Version of installed plugin: "cordova-plugin-compat@1.0.0" does not satisfy dependency plugin requirement
    "cordova-plugin-compat@^1.1.0". Try --force to use installed plugin as dependency.
```

I really lost in this error, can you explain me what is this error and how to handle this ?

Comment: try this `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat ` and build again.

Comment: Great added it to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just remove this plugin with `ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-compat`
and after that reinstall this plugin by `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat` and this problem disapper.

Plugin "cordova-plugin-compat" is not present in the project. See `cordova plugin list`.

Answer (score 3):

Remove and after that install by
`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat` and build again.